# How to know if the SPUser is a "real" user or a system user like "search"?

Tags: sharepoint

I have built an http module that detect file openings. I don't want any alert to be raised when the file is crawled by a system account like 'search' for instance. I have tried to use isApplicationPrincipal and several others but it didn't work.

How would you do to keep only track of "real" users modifications ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? By the way, I'm interested in your HTTP module that detects file openings. Any guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint search index crawler uses "Robot-something" as HTTP user agent. I don't know what the exact string look like, sorry for that.

You can check if the [`HttpRequest.UserAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property contains "Robot":

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Robot", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
{
  // Code that runs for real users only.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use SharePoint Audits? They create a report when a user opens a file. And they are able to track file openings not only in the web site but in clients applications too.